# Facing compilation error while trying to import the package in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I am a newbie in Ballerina, and I am trying to import some OpenAPI Connector (For example ballerinax
/
fraudlabspro.frauddetection) into my Ballerina project. However I keep facing the error as stated at below:

```
Compiling source
        admin/test2:0.1.0
ballerina: Oh no, something really went wrong. Bad. Sad.

We appreciate it if you can report the code that broke Ballerina in
https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues with the
log you get below and your sample code.

We thank you for helping make us better.

[2023-11-08 07:48:35,043] SEVERE {b7a.log.crash} - Cannot read field "flags" because "type.tsymbol" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "flags" because "type.tsymbol" is null
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:2709)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.expressions.BLangTypeInit.accept(BLangTypeInit.java:70)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeExpr(CodeAnalyzer.java:3514)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:3196)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.expressions.BLangCheckedExpr.accept(BLangCheckedExpr.java:70)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeExpr(CodeAnalyzer.java:3514)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:1717)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.BLangSimpleVariable.accept(BLangSimpleVariable.java:59)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.visitNode(SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.java:215)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeNode(CodeAnalyzer.java:349)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:1834)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.statements.BLangSimpleVariableDef.accept(BLangSimpleVariableDef.java:55)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.visitNode(SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.java:215)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeNode(CodeAnalyzer.java:349)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:538)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.BLangBlockFunctionBody.accept(BLangBlockFunctionBody.java:65)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.visitNode(SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.java:215)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeNode(CodeAnalyzer.java:349)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visitFunction(CodeAnalyzer.java:513)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:456)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.BLangFunction.accept(BLangFunction.java:81)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.visitNode(SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.java:215)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeNode(CodeAnalyzer.java:349)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyzeTopLevelNodes(CodeAnalyzer.java:338)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:326)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.visit(CodeAnalyzer.java:280)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.BLangPackage.accept(BLangPackage.java:172)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.tree.SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.visitNode(SimpleBLangNodeAnalyzer.java:215)
        at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.semantics.analyzer.CodeAnalyzer.analyze(CodeAnalyzer.java:314)
        at io.ballerina.projects.internal.CompilerPhaseRunner.codeAnalyze(CompilerPhaseRunner.java:196)
        at io.ballerina.projects.internal.CompilerPhaseRunner.performTypeCheckPhases(CompilerPhaseRunner.java:119)
        at io.ballerina.projects.ModuleContext.compileInternal(ModuleContext.java:435)
        at io.ballerina.projects.ModuleCompilationState$1.compile(ModuleCompilationState.java:45)
        at io.ballerina.projects.ModuleContext.compile(ModuleContext.java:383)
        at io.ballerina.projects.PackageCompilation.compileModulesInternal(PackageCompilation.java:208)
        at io.ballerina.projects.PackageCompilation.compileModules(PackageCompilation.java:192)
        at io.ballerina.projects.PackageCompilation.compile(PackageCompilation.java:99)
        at io.ballerina.projects.PackageCompilation.from(PackageCompilation.java:94)
        at io.ballerina.projects.PackageContext.getPackageCompilation(PackageContext.java:242)
        at io.ballerina.projects.Package.getCompilation(Package.java:150)
        at io.ballerina.projects.Package.runCodeGeneratorPlugins(Package.java:319)
        at io.ballerina.cli.task.CompileTask.execute(CompileTask.java:142)
        at io.ballerina.cli.TaskExecutor.executeTasks(TaskExecutor.java:40)
        at io.ballerina.cli.cmd.RunCommand.execute(RunCommand.java:223)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
        at io.ballerina.cli.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:58)

ERROR [test2:(1:1,1:1)] Compilation failed due to: Cannot read field "flags" because "type.tsymbol" is null
error: compilation contains errors
```

I have try dig up on the documentation and also GitHub, but no clue on what exact is this error about. Can someone help me on this?

Below is the code from my main.bal:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/fraudlabspro.frauddetection as ff;

public function main() {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
    ff:Client baseClient = check new Client();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please change the code as follows?

```php
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/fraudlabspro.frauddetection as ff;

public function main() returns error? {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
    ff:Client baseClient = check new ff:Client();
}
```

You need to change the return type of the `main` function to `error?` because you use the [check](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/check-expression/) expression. When creating the `ff:Client` object, you cannot omit `ff:` prefix. The reason is explained in https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/41474#issuecomment-1780670293.

Comment: Hi Nadeeshan, thanks for the solution! I have managed to solve the issue by using your answer.